# How to clean up all maven projects with linux find command?

Tags: linux, maven, cygwin

I want to clean up all my maven projects at once. But I want to avoid to do it step-by-step going through all the folders manually and call `mvn clean`. So I thought to do this with the find command. I tried the following call:

```
find . -name pom.xml -exec mvn clean {} \;
```

The result was the error message: *find: missing argument for "-exec"*.

Now my question: is it possible to do such a call with *find* and *exec*? I thought I can use every command as an argument for *find -exec*.

Thanks in advance

Hardie

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you expand what exec will run for you:

```
mvn clean dir1/dir2/pom.xml
```

You'll see that you treated the pom-file as a maven goal.

You should use -f flag, and apostrophes (to prevent globing):

```
find . -name pom.xml -exec mvn clean -f '{}' \;
```

As for me, I use this command

```
find . -name 'target' -a -type d -exec rm -rfv '{}' \;
```

This will delete all target folders.

Comment: That's it. With the apostrophe it works fine. Your solution is also a good one. Thank you very much.

Comment: If your using Cygwin on Windows use `pwd` - 

```find `pwd` -name 'pom.xml' -exec mvn clean '{}' \;``` or

```find `pwd` -name 'target' -a -type -exec rm -rfv '{}' \;```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what version of mvn command supports specifying pom file like that, but for e.g. Maven 3.x that doesn't work. We need a small change. Either run with **-execdir** which automatically changes the directory for us to the location of found pom file (and generally safer than -exec):

```
find . -name pom.xml -execdir mvn clean \;
```

or with specified alternate pom file option **-f**:

```
find . -name pom.xml -exec mvn clean -f '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you, like I, have quite a lot of maven projects checked out, the suggested approaches might take hours.
I currently have 700 projects checked out.

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -type f -name pom.xml | 
  sed 's|/pom.xml$|/target|' | 
  xargs -I{} bash -c '[ -d {} ] && echo {}' | 
  xargs -I{} bash -c 'mvn clean -f "$(sed "s|/target$|/pom.xml|" <<< "{}")"'
```

What I do here is I test that a target folder exist before I apply the clean command.
This makes it so that I do not activate maven unless there is reason to, an the execution time is then linear to the projects I've worked in recently, not the total number of projects.
You might need to fiddle a bit with the maxdepth as well, in case my number does not fit your bill.